# numpyでベクトルの向きを考慮して2つのベクトル間の角度を計算したい

Tags: python, numpy

まず以下のようにして、
ベクトルxとベクトルyの角度を計算する関数を書きます。

```
import numpy as np

def angle(x, y):

    dot_xy = np.dot(x, y)
    norm_x = np.linalg.norm(x)
    norm_y = np.linalg.norm(y)
    cos = dot_xy / (norm_x*norm_y)
    rad = np.arccos(cos)
    theta = rad * 180 / np.pi

    return theta
```

次にこの関数を用いて、
以下のベクトルxとベクトルyの角度を計算します。

```
x = np.array([1, 0, 1])
y = np.array([1, 1, 1])
print angle(x, y)
```

この結果はもちろん、45.0となります。

ここで、上記のベクトルxと以下のベクトルzの角度を計算します。

```
z = np.array([1, -1, 1])
print angle(x, z)
```

この場合ももちろん、上記と同じ角度である45.0が出力されます。

しかしここで、
xとyで計算した時を「正の方向」とした上で、
xとzの角度は45.0ではなく、315.0と出力したいです。

numpyではどのようにすれば、
ベクトルの向きを固定して角度を計算することができるでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: xy平面上のベクトル、つまり三番目の要素が常に 0 であるベクトル同士の角度でしょうか。一般に三次元のベクトルだと、最初に回転軸と回転方向を決めないと判断できませんので。

Comment: ベクトル積のz成分を計算して符号を判定すればよいのでは

Comment: @Hideki すみません。例が悪かったようです。一般の三次元ベクトルを考えていました。

Comment: @pgrho たしかに符号の判定で簡単に解決できる問題でした。
少し難しく考えすぎていたようです。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: @neco システム上回答がないとまずいので、お手数ですが修正結果を回答として投稿しておいてください

Comment: @pgrho 了解しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

コメントを頂いた通り、符号の判定で解決できる問題でした。
お手数をおかけしました。ありがとうございます。